# Python: vector represented as a combination of list of vectors

Tags: python, math

Say I have a list of vectors

```
VectorList = [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]
```

and say I have a vector x

```
x = [0,3,0,1]
```

then x can in this case be written as a linear combination of the other vectors:

```
[0,3,0,1] = a*[1,0,0,0] + b*[0,1,0,0] + c*[0,0,1,0] + d*[0,0,0,1]
```

where a = 0, b = 3, c = 0 and d = 1

is there a general way in Python to check IF a vector can be written as a linear combination of a list of vectors and find the scalar-multiples of this?
I am a beginner in python and I can do it intuitively... But how would one solve this in Python? I have worked on this problem for so many hours

Remember, the list of vectors might not always be as clear cut as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to solve a linear system of equations? I would suggest having a look at <strike>[numpy.matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)</strike> and [numpy linalg](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html). Numpy has a lot of useful math stuff in it :).

EDIT:

It looks like the function you want is `numpy.linalg.solve(a,b)` (where `b` is x in your case) which will throw a `LinAlgError` if no solution can be found.

Comment: `numpy.matrix`? Bad idea; it's convenient at first, but weird indexing behavior and inconsistencies with ndarrays make them confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've never used it myself. Will strike it :).